# Fluent hierarchy

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following situation with fluent nhibernate:

```
public class Stuff
{
    public Stuff()
    {
        Entities = new List<Entity>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Stuff Stuff { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Animal : Entity
{
    public virtual string Species { get; set; }
}
```

And then, i have the following code to use automap and generate these mappings:

```
        var sessionFactory =
            Fluently.Configure().Database(persistenceConfigurer).Mappings(
                m =>
                m.AutoMappings.Add(
                    AutoMap.Source(new Types(typeof(Entity), typeof(Person), typeof(Animal), typeof(Stuff))))
                    .ExportTo(@"e:\")).ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema).BuildSessionFactory();
```

however, what's happening is that i get the following exception:

---> NHibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: ConsoleApplication1.Models.Entity

if i make the entity class non abstract this works, however, i'd like to avoid having that table in the database but still maintain the hierarchy concept with the re

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your auto mappings like this

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(yourConfiguration).IgnoreBase<Entity>();
```

Not only will this ignore your `Entity` base class but you don't need to add each entity manually so long as each model inherits from `Entity`.